# autocad 2008 - copy object between two open drawings

Tags: vba, autocad

I'm trying to copy a polyline from a drawing to another

```
'save reference to source drawing
dim sourceDWG as acadDocument
set sourceDWG = thisdrawing

'opening a new drawing
dim destinationDWG as acadDocument
Set destinationDWG = Application.Documents.Add

'users choses the polyline
Dim poli As Object
Dim punct(0 To 2) As Double
ThisDrawing.Utility.GetEntity poli, punct, "please, choose a poliline"

'copy object from sourceDWG to destinationDWG
Dim objects(0 To 0) As Object
Set objects(0) = poli 
sourceDWG.CopyObjects obiecte
```

Problem here is with the last line. SourceDWG points to current thisDrawing - destination drawing, not source drawing. This code is typed inside stack overflow editor so it might contain typeo's

Answer (score 1):

Solved: source document is poli.document, destination is thisdrawing.modelspace

```
poli.Document.CopyObjects obiecte, ThisDrawing.ModelSpace
```